# Problem on autorotate for UITabBarController and modal views

Tags: iphone, uitabbarcontroller, autorotate, modalviewcontroller

I have a problem opening and closing of a ModalView: when the user touches the button to open the view, or when it touches the button to close it, appears this message in Console:

The view controller  returned NO from _shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation: for all interface orientations. It should support at least one orientation.

The ModalView is associated with a UITableViewController, contained in a UINavigationController in turn inserted into a UITabBarController. I can not understand how to solve this problem.

Answer (score 1):

Well this is very old now, but just in case it helps someone: your code probably looks like this:

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation {
    return NO;
}
```

The problem there is that you are essentially saying that your view won't support ANY orientation :)

It should look something like this:

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation {
    // Support portrait only
    return (toInterfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait);
}
```

Trivial but maybe this helps someone in future.